# Java method for android:windowSoftInputMode attribute

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

The XML attribute `android:windowSoftInputMode` for an activity in manifest file is available. Is there any related Java method for same attribute ?

For getting same functionality I tried `InputMethodManager` methods like (hide, show, toggle, etc.) but those are not working.

If anybody know Java method for windowSoftInputMode attribute please reply me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

//you can use this line

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
       WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```